# Identifying RAM usage in R session

Tags: r

this seems super simple, but I don't think gc() is giving me the right answer.

```
> gc()

              used     (Mb)  gc trigger     (Mb)    max used     (Mb)
Ncells     1232798     65.9     6534196    349.0    10522819    562.0
Vcells 21975737289 167661.6 39920139363 304566.5 28573603399 217999.3
```

Which number above tells me how much ram my R session is currently using? Because when I do top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 XXXX XXXXX     XX   0  173204   2872   1684 R   1.0  0.0   0:00.12 top
 XXXX XXXXX     XX   0  187348   2560   1196 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.80 sshd
 XXXX XXXXX     XX   0  127336   5440   1812 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.18 bash
 XXXX XXXXX     XX   0   55.9g  50.7g  17372 S   0.0  6.7 391:11.32 R
 XXXX XXXXX     XX   0  189412   2576   1196 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.85 sshd
 XXXX XXXXX     XX   0  127204   5244   1684 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.18 bash
```

None of the numbers from the R gc() command look like the 50GB of RAM that this top command tells me I am using for R

How can I get R to tell me how much RAM I'm using?

Comment: Use `ps::ps_memory_info()` for determining how much memory is currently used, such as the "Resident Set Size" (rss). I don't recommend you attempt to infer how much RAM is being used by looking at `gc()`.

Comment: I did object size and ps_memory_info and once again I am getting conflicting answers:
> object.size(temp_df)
23298833680 bytes
> ps_memory_info()
    rss     vms  shared    text     lib    data   dirty
8794696 7831766    2744       1       0 8680577       0